# MySQL used ALL Type while searching on Primary Key

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

My table schema:

[image: This is my Table Schema]

My above table has ~10L data. While using EXPLAIN, it shows as,

[image]

From this, **type** shows **ALL**, **Extra** shows **Using where** and **rows** not in **O(1)**. But, for searching on primary key, the **type** should be **const**, **rows** be in **O(1)** ?? I can't able to figure out the issue, which results in slowing the queries.

Comment: Your id field is varchar while you pass the value you are looking for as a number. Either convert your id to number or pass the value as string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `id` field is varchar while you pass the value you are looking for as a number.

This means that mysql has to perform an implicit data conversion and [will not be able to use the index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) for looking up the value:

> For comparisons of a string column with a number, MySQL cannot use an
>   index on the column to look up the value quickly. If str_col is an
>   indexed string column, the index cannot be used when performing the
>   lookup in the following statement:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE str_col=1;
> ```
>
> The reason for this is that
>   there are many different strings that may convert to the value 1, such
>   as '1', ' 1', or '1a'.

Either convert your `id` field to number or pass the value as string.

Answer (score 0):

As your id column is varchar, you need to provide it String while searching.

Try, `id= '123456'`

Reason:
Since you are comparing a varchar column to Int, it will first convert all rows to Int, and then match it with 123456(int).